# C# Asana POST new task returns error 400 (Bad request)

Tags: c#, asana

I have a problem with creating new task in Asana from my app.

Post method:

```
protected static T Post<T>(string route, object action = null, object parameters = null) where T : BaseResult, new()
    {
        var result = new T();

        try
        {
            var actionUrl             = GetActionUrl(route, action);
            var request               = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(actionUrl);
            request.Credentials       = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Accept            = "application/json";
            request.Method            = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + ApiKey);

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                var contentJSON       = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
                request.ContentType   = "application/json";

                using (var s = request.GetRequestStream())
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.UTF8))
                        sw.Write(contentJSON);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                result   = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.IsOk    = false;
            result.Message = ex.GetMessage();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Action URL: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/*MyWorkspace*/tasks
JSON:`{"data":{"name":"TestTask1","notes":"Test note","workspace":"*MyWorkspace*","assignee":"*MyAssignee"}}`

But Asana returns me "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

If I change request.ContentType to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", I get no errors, but Asana returns me new task with empty fields.

What my next steps to fix issue should be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ApiKey (and not a Personal Access Token), I believe that your Authorization Header should be

`"Authorization: Basic " + EncodedAuthInfo`

where

`EncodedAuthInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ApiKey + ":"))`

See [How do I connect to the Asana Rest API using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317171/how-do-i-connect-to-the-asana-rest-api-using-c) or the Using Basic Authentication section in https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth for details on using basic authentication.

I'm also a little confused by what you mean when you say that

`JSON = {"data": {"name": "TestTask1"} ...`

Is this the HTTP response that you expect?

Anyways, hopefully what I've outlined helps.

Comment: Sorry, for confusing variable naming. I'm using Personal Access Token and I successfully GET information from Asana, but I'm unable to POST new tasks, projects and so on.
This JSON is what I'm sending to ASANA. 
As I understand from documentation, fields, not mentioned in JSON, will be set to default values.

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying. Would you be able to show me the raw URL of the request? I think that would make it easier to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I think that specifying
`request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`
is the right call.

Something tells me the issue is with the section where you write to the steam. I'm not an expert on C# but perhaps following the usage here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc(v=vs.110).aspx would be helpful?

Comment: Hi again, Mark!
The problem still persists.
Even if I set request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and encode request as in the msdn manual, you've mentioned. No errors returned by asana. No task created.
Is there any sandbox in Asana, where I can see server-side errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I think I've got what's blocking you sorted out.

Imagine the scenario where you post to

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/123456/tasks
```

and you pass in the request body the parameter

```
"workspace":"789012"
```

What should the Asana platform do with this data? You've inadvertently specified the workspace twice with conflicting numbers. For this reason, **you cannot specify the workspace id in the data when hitting an endpoint which also contains the workspace id in the URL**.

The documentation is confusing on this point, because we don't clarify which parameters are found in the URL and which parameters are found in the JSON in the request body. I'm actually fixing this very soon! If this is indeed what's causing the issue, I'm sorry that we were not clear on this.

Personally, I think it might be a better user experience to allow the workspace to be duplicated in the parameter data if and only if it's identical to the one in the URL, but right now, we simply check to see that there is only one value for the workspace id. If there are more than one, even if they are the same one, we return the `400` error code.

You might consider parsing the response body, even on errors. In it, we try to provide fairly decent information about what was wrong about the request. For example, when testing my hunch about your request, what I got back was:

```
"errors":[{"message":"Duplicate field: workspace", ...}]
```

If we've done a good job about sending back informative messages, I hope you'll find this even more useful than an Asana sandbox! If this is not the issue, feel free to comment; I'll be happy to dive into this further.